# HTML table inside jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a search functionality using a jquery dialog.  The search dialog is displayed as a modal pop up from the parent screen and I want to display the search results in a html table within the dialog.
However, the html table gets displayed on the parent screen.   I've tried placing the dialog code in the parent html, as an external file, but the results are always the same.
Is it okay to use html tables inside jquery dialogs?   If it is not, what would be the alternate mechanism to display grid data.

Browser is IE8, OS is Windows 7

```
    <div id="searchDialog">
        <div id="qryPane">
        </div>
        <div id="searchResults">
          <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Col1</th>
                 <th>Col2</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody></tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _"Is it okay to use html tables inside jquery dialogs?"_ Of course it is. However you've left out your jQuery and any code that would let us reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the mark up itself and I was able to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the mark up itself and I was able to fix it.   I was trying to add the dialog to an existing page (as a jsp include) that had a lot of code.   I moved the include from the top to the bottom of the page and that resolved the problem.
I do not think the location of the include itself was the problem, but its possible the existing markup (which is made up of pieces of html code assembled via includes) had an issue.